# One Array - Multiple sections - NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have one big array with many values. I've sorted out the sections but I can't seem to get the indexpath right.

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is that if the previous section has 50 rows, the next indexpath.row should be 51->. The one after that should be 60-> and so fourth.

```
NSLog(@"current indexpath.row: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"current section: %ld",(long)indexPath.section);
for (int i = indexPath.section; i == indexPath.section; i++) {
            NSLog(@"number of rows: %ld",(long)[self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]);
            NSLog(@"in section: %ld",(long)indexPath.section);
    if (i++) {
        // add previous number of rows plus current

        int previousRows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section*2];
        NSLog(@"now indexpath: %ld",(long)previousRows+indexPath.row);
    }
}
```

I hope I've made my question clear enough for you to understand.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection means number of rows in each section. For every section indexpath.row will start from 0. What do you exactly want to do from this?

Comment: @BhanuPriya, If I'm on section 15 for example, I want the indexpath.row to be everything from 1-14. So indexpath on section 15 would be 100+

Comment: Why do you need everything in 1 large array? An array of arrays is a much better structure for this. This allows you to access rows like this `data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`.

Comment: exactly, you should maintain array of arrays

Comment: @JefferyThomas Because my array changes dynamically depending on how many items i receive from the JSON response. Creating and allocating 40+ arrays when I only need 5 or 10 is not effective.

Comment: @FilipBusic have you tested for this? Why assume a performance issue without proof? ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29) — Donald Knuth

Comment: @JefferyThomas You're absolutely right.. But there is no way I'm going to create 100 arrays & worry if the JSON returns 101 arrays which will kill the app. However, Michal's answer was correct & works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` doesn't work this way. `NSIndexPath` starts from 0 for every section.

If I understand correctly, you want to know the global index value to access the array. For that case, I have been using this little method:

```
- (int)getGlobalRowFor:(int)row at:(int)section {
    if(section == 0) {
        return row;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < section; i++) {
            // This is where you put your own numbers for section counts. 
            // This is my model, yours could be different.
            count += [[[self.sections objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sectionCount"] intValue];
        }
        return count + row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.. However, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: So maybe you could clarify what exactly you want to achieve. It seems to me like this from your question...

Comment: Imagine having an array that changes dynamically depending on how big of an JSON response you receive. So implementing if(section==1)-> up to if(section==100) is going to take a lot of un-useful space.. So.. I have an array with about 60 objects that I'd like to store in UITableview. When I change to a different section, the indexpath.row is 0. So I'd like to count the objects in the previous section and add it to the current value. Example: if the previous section had 10 objects, the next indexpath.row would be 11-> up

Comment: And how is it different from the method I posted? It takes all the previous section counts and adds them all together so you get always the global index - for section 1 with 10 objects, you will receive 11 if you ask for global index with indexPath row:0, section:1. I am not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. However, I'm not sure what you're doing here: `[[[self.sections objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sectionCount"] intValue];`

Comment: That's just my model where I store the counts for each section. You have to store the numbers somewhere - the numbers saying how many rows are in each section, then this method just adds them up.

Comment: Do you mind showing me the code you use to count the rows at each section?

Comment: It won't be helpful, it is made for dynamic loading when I don't know if the section has ended with the next batch of data or not. But basically you have to have the section counts ready before you reload the data.